# Communicating between shell script and C

Tags: c, bash, shell

I've a shell script file which randomly generates a location and copy some files to this randomly generated location.

I also have a different C code that needs to access this randomly generated location to access the copied files.

However, both shell script and C code work independently (in order of shell script and C code). The C code is called by a third application, so it is impossible to pass the location data to C.

How can I securely save this "randomly generated location" data somewhere that C code can access.

I am running these scripts on Mac and would prefer a solution that helps keep these data into memory or does not make file at a common location (like /tmp, /var/tmp etc)

Comment: One typically uses *arguments* to pass information to programs. Can you modify the programs? For example to accept a special argument to specify the location?

Comment: No I cannot. For sake of this question, it would be safe to assume that C program cannot accept and arguments

Comment: Why do you think it would be cleaner to somehow access a certain shared location in memory than to read it from a certain file in a common location?

Comment: Because, while in memory, it would be more difficult for others to easily access the temporary location. If I create a file, it can still be seen.

Comment: Well, you could write the file to be only readable by a certain user and/or group and use that as an authentication mechanism, whereas if the memory was just accessible to anyone (who knows its location) it would only be more obscure, not more secure. Of course you can encrypt either the memory or the file.

Comment: Yes, it would be more obscure and that should just work for me.

Comment: But, even if its file with encryption, please could you provide me some lead?

Comment: Since you specify Mac (presumably running macOS), you could also consider keychain or user defaults instead of file.

Comment: I'm not sure how to access user defaults. Do you have any idea around it? Now exploring keychain option as you suggested.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH2-SW8

Comment: This looks awesome, please reply this in answer and I'll accept it as answer, if no one else provides a more relevant answer suited to my case, i.e. related to memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to share the information. Personally I don't find saving to a file to be a problem, since you can use the filesystem's access control to limit access, and/or encrypt the file.

However, specifically on macOS there are some other ways, such as [User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH2-SW8) (accessible from command-line with `defaults`), and Keychain (accessible from command-line with `security`).

Saving to user defaults is effectively saving to a file (accessible by that user), so for security (other than through obscurity) you would still need to encrypt the data. Meanwhile Keychain is built for storing things securely, but setting up access to it is more difficult (and you may inadvertently grant your shell interpreter permanent access).

Still, it may be worthwhile to try something like:

```
security add-generic-password -a myUserName -s myService -w '/foo/bar/baz'

security find-generic-password -g -a myUserName -s myService
```